# How to get the name of the list

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

I create a list first

```
List<String> dummy1 = new List<String>();
List<String> dummy2 = new List<String>();
List<String> dummy3 = new List<String>();
List<String> dummy4 = new List<String>();
```

Before I add the list to Dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, List<String>> _d = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>()
{
  {1, dummy1},
  {2, dummy2}, 
  {3, dummy3}, 
  {4, dummy4}, 
};
```

then I want to have the name of the list by looping the key

```
foreach (var key in _d.Keys)
{
  MessageBox.Show(_d[key].GetType().Name);
}
```

but the output is `list 1`, I want to get the

```
dummy1
dummy2
dummy3
dummy4
```

Comment: In short; you can't. Not without using some really funky syntax to capture the variables.

Comment: I wonder if the new"nameof" expression in upcoming c# 6.0 can do this where expression trees can't. ..doubt it because of the dictionary, but maybe some magic there?

Comment: @JasonW I highly doubt it. As I understand it, nameof() is done at compile time and merely replaces the call with a string. For example, `var prop = nameof(dummy1)` gets compiled to `var prop = "dummy1"`. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a custom class that inherits from `List<string>` and have a Name property.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyList dummy1 = new MyList("dummy1");
        MyList dummy2 = new MyList("dummy2");
        MyList dummy3 = new MyList("dummy3");
        MyList dummy4 = new MyList("dummy4");

        Dictionary<int, MyList> _d = new Dictionary<int, MyList>()
        {
            {1, dummy1},
            {2, dummy2}, 
            {3, dummy3}, 
            {4, dummy4}, 
        };

        foreach (var key in _d.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_d[key].Name);
        }
    }
}

public class MyList : List<String>
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public MyList(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
dummy1
dummy2
dummy3
dummy4
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OtelqZ)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning data to a variable name and you are going to get the variable name in order to access the data. I would create a simple object with a Name and List and add it to the Dictionary.

Comment: Reflection won't even work in this case. As the code is compiled, those variable names are lost. The only way I've ever seen to get variable names is through expression trees, but in this case, even that won't work since the variable name is lost once assigned within the dictionary.

Comment: @JasonW: Correct! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, you can only do this with really funky syntax. Here's an example of what I mean

```
void Main()
{
    List<String> dummy1 = new List<String>();
    List<String> dummy2 = new List<String>();
    List<String> dummy3 = new List<String>();
    List<String> dummy4 = new List<String>();

    var _d = new Dictionary<int, Expression<Func<List<String>>>>()
    {
        {1, () => dummy1},
        {2, () => dummy2}, 
        {3, () => dummy3}, 
        {4, () => dummy4}, 
    };
    foreach(var kvp in _d)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(kvp.Value.nameof());
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class TestExtension
{
    public static String nameof<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> accessor)
    {
        return nameof(accessor.Body);
    }

    public static String nameof<T, TT>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TT>> propertyAccessor)
    {
        return nameof(propertyAccessor.Body);
    }

    private static String nameof(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            var memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression == null)
                return null;
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The main issue is that you need the dictionary to store an expression, rather than a List

Secondly, to actually ACCESS the list, you need to do this:

```
var list = _d[1].Compile()();
```

And lastly, if dummy1 ever gets reassigned, you'll lose the reference to the list you're expecting.

In short, it's very unlikely that you need to do this. It's rare that the variable names in code should actually affect behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a Dictionary that stores an int and a list:

```
Dictionary<int, List<String>>
```

Create a Dictionary that stores the name of the list with the list:

```
Dictionary<string, List<String>>
```

If you want to then get the int number that corresponds to the list, you can use a normal `for` loop and see what value is at the location when let's say `i = 1`.